# Array unexpectedly not modified by function

Tags: arrays, random, rust

The code runs just fine but all values are 0, when they should be numbers randomly generated from a range of 0 and 60 / 300, as in the code. Using Rust playground as ide.

```
#![allow(dead_code, mutable_transmutes, non_camel_case_types, non_snake_case,
         non_upper_case_globals, unused_assignments, unused_mut)]
const MAX: usize = 16;
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct time {
    h: i32,
    m: i32,
    s: i32,
}

fn rnd (mut x: [time; MAX], y: usize) {
    use rand::Rng;
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut i: usize = 0;
    while i < y {
        x[i].h = rng.gen_range(0..300);
        x[i].m = rng.gen_range(0..60);
        x[i].s = rng.gen_range(0..60);
        i+=1;
    }
}

fn main () {
    let mut a: [time; MAX] = [time{h: 0, m: 0, s: 0,}; MAX];
    let mut i: usize = 0;
    rnd(a, MAX);
    while i < MAX {
        println!("{}", a[i].h);
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're copying the parameter `x`; you need a reference in order to change the outer value.

Comment: Also, why all the allows? Some of them are very useful to not allow in order to make sure programs are consistent and easier to read (like disallowing `non_camel_case_types`, `non_snake_case`, `non_upper_case_globals`).

Comment: Should we update the question title to something like "Rust language array modification not working"?

Comment: @effect no. Why would we? Adding the language in the question is bad practice, that's what tags are for, and everything is working as expected here, it's just the OP misunderstanding that Rust doesn't pass-by-reference/pointer by default.

Comment: @mcarton The previous question title was "Rust language, issues using random", I was proposing to redirect the focus from the rand library to talking about arrays. Looks like the title was already renamed by the time you saw my comment :) I agree removing rust entirely and adding a tag is even better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first line of code with all the `allow` does exactly one thing: it prevents the compiler from helping you.

Let's remove the `unused_mut`. Now the compiler warns you:

```
warning: variable does not need to be mutable
  --> src/main.rs:24:9
   |
24 |     let mut a: [time; MAX] = [time{h: 0, m: 0, s: 0,}; MAX];
   |         ----^
   |         |
   |         help: remove this `mut`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_mut)]` on by default
```

So, why is `a` not modified ?

It's because you don't give a reference to the `rnd` function but a *copy* ([arrays](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html) all implement `Copy` when the contained type does).

Now it's clear what you need to do:

Change your function to

```
fn rnd (x: &mut [time; MAX], y: usize) {
```

so that you pass a mut reference, then call it as

```
rnd(&mut a, MAX);
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=34d844420623b0d7efbbc7fbd2282299)

The next step is of course to stop allowing everything. Compiler warnings should very rarely be ignored.